# Where is the usage of (type-name) for C language defined in the language specification?

Tags: c

It seems that `(type-name)` returns the default value for the type.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("value: %ld\n", ((time_t) -1));
  printf("value: %d\n", ((int) -1));
}
```

Use `gcc code.c` to compile it. Running `./.aout` produces:

```
value: -1
value: -1
```

I am using `GCC 8.1.0` on `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`.

And [TIME(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) has the following text:

> On error, ((time_t) -1) is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

I browsed the C11 language specification [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). But I can't find a description about the above usage.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a little harsh, but if you don't know about *casting* then you need to either read your books more thoroughly, or stop skipping classes.

Comment: It's in section 6.5.4

Comment: You never use the time() function. How can you have its return value? (time_t) is a cast.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is basic C knowledge, and it is not a programming question

Comment: Should have looked slightly more diligently and played a bit more with spaces, `(type-name)` is not in the standard, but `( type-name )` *is*.

Comment: @P__J__: Neither of those are [the criteria for what may be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (Being a programming problem is one qualifying reason—in a list of several reasons.)

Comment: Try the same with `((time_t) -2))` or `((time_t) 42))`.

Comment: The information about cast operators is found in section 6.5.4 Cast operators.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I have mistakenly interpreted `((time_t) -1)` as something like `a - b`.  This is the cause of my confusion. I know C type cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that (type-name) returns the default value for the type.

What's that even supposed to mean? There exists no default values for types in C. Your two printf lines does this:

- `printf("value: %ld\n", ((time_t) -1));`

  Here `-1` has type `int`. You force a conversion from `int` to `time_t`, the latter having an unspecified format, other than being "a real type capable of representing times".

  Then you lie to the program and say that the value passed is of type `long int`. You invoke undefined behavior, anything can happen. In your particular case, it seems to give the original value `-1`. It could as well print garbage or cause a program crash.

  This has absolutely nothing to do with the `time()` function, which isn't present anywhere in the code.
- `printf("value: %d\n", ((int) -1));`

  `-1` has type `int`. You tell the compiler to convert from `int` to `int`. The compiler, being polite, doesn't question why you'd write such meaningless code, but likely just pre-process it back into `-1`.

  You then tell `printf` that you want to print your `int` with value `-1` as an `int`. And then it does that.

---

> I browsed the C11 language specification N1570. But I can't find a description about the above usage

See C11 6.5.4 *Cast operators* and C11 7.21.6.1 *The fprintf function*.